# Power BI Drilldown and Total

Tags: powerbi, drilldown

I am working on a table and creating drilldown in power bi matrix. Showing Drilldown From Member to To User. From member will drilldown to User and date. On the column header I see Instead of To User it shows First To User (red arrow). Second After drilling on the same line of From Member there is one of the To User (Blue arrow and yellow highlight) and next to it , it has SUM. Similarly at the bottom at TOTAL there is one To User Name and then SUM. My question is (1) how to remove First from the Fisrt User To. (2) How to remove Yellow Highlited Name[image] . (3) How to remove name from the TOTAL row. Please see image for clarity. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ans to question 1** Edit the column name as shown in the image. You can update it to any label you wants and the column header will show the label accordingly.

[image]

**Ans to question 2 & 3** There is no exact configuration in Matrix for your scenario. In addition, adding Text column in the **Values** list also do not make that sense as you already facing issue with that column. In Matrix, Values column always considered for Aggregation and for Text type column you can take any of the option from - First/Last/Count. Now with those options, you can not achieve your required output.

**Work around (Best for your case):** This will solve your issue **1,2 & 3** together in one go. Create a **Custom Column** to your table as below-

```
date_user = your_table_name[Date] & " : " & your_table_name[user]
```

**Now,** add both your column **From Member** and **date_user** to the Matrix's Rows and **Sale** column to Matrix's Values property. The final output will be something like below (with my test data)-

[image]

**====================================================**

**ADD USER DRILL DOWN**

Add **User**(My Case Sub Category) column to Matrix row as below-

[image]

The final output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: There is any way to do in the following way:   -  electronics

Comment: there is any way to do (drilldown) like this:   first on the electronics (as shown) then on fan/TV then this will give individual dates.  - electronics

Comment: Can you add an image with your expected output?

Comment: not sure how to add image in comment sections. trying to figure it out.

Comment: add to your question.

Comment: @Paper, if I understand you correct, yes this is possible. You just need to add your sub category/User column in between From Member and date_user to the Matrix's Rows. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To remove subtotals you can turn off the subtotal option at the paint roll while selecting the visual. During my test I was able to remove all totals using only this option.

[image: Option location]

Hope this solves all your questions. Feel free to add more details and I'll do my best to help.